# Proper usage of NServiceBus in Asp.NET web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nservicebus

Have I figured  [Using NServiceBus with ASP.NET MVC](http://docs.particular.net/samples/web/asp-mvc-application/) correctly?

1. User sends his request to WebApi controller
2. Controller (client) creates command and sends it to bus to release worker thread, so api can handle more requests.
3. Console application (server) subscribes for that command and handles it via some domain logic
4. Information goes back to the client (controller)
5. Client returns request back to the user.

Is console application just for the brevity and i should use something such as windows service to handle commands?

[image]

Comment: The only issue I can see is that your diagram is suggesting request response, that will introduce it's challenges in real time (how is the second controller going to notify the client of the returned data?), if you are doing messaging, design your system in a fire and forget paradigm. make sense?

Comment: @SeanFarmar You mean in a way that i will not notify user "Booking Confirmed",  i should notify something as "Booking Requested", and send an email when background processing is done, or even use web-sockets to get back to him?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Async Controller yes, you are correct.

As far as the server is concerned, yes we use console applications to make the samples easy to run. For an actual service I would recommend checking out the [windows service bootstrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.Bootstrap.WindowsService) we have created. More information is available at http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/windows-service